# What are the specific requirements for the Documentation badge Bluebook?

Tags: support, badges, documentation

I'm asking this because I believe I fulfilled the requirements for the [Bluebook](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5850/bluebook) badge:

> First citation of a topic or example you've contributed to.

But others have been awarded the badge while I have not. Comparing their contributions to mine, it appears to be awarded on the "first time an answer is written that links to a documentation topic you contributed to".

But in practice it seems to only apply to *new* answers. The answer I added my link to was a year or two old. Additionally, both recipients of the badge are the *sole contributors* to the Documentation topic for which they were awarded the bag, while the topic I linked to has several contributors... including ones more recent than me!

As such I believe my interpretation is correct, it's just that it only counts on answers posted after the Documentation topics were contributed to, and not on edits to older answers.

Can a staff member speak to whether that's correct or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The badge is keyed off of the ["first time an answer that cites documentation you contributed to is upvoted: +5"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) reputation change:

[image: example cited]

If you don't have that entry in your reputation history, you aren't going to get the badge. In turn, that reputation is not earned unless both the example and the answer have been upvoted by someone else.

It looks like the "example cited" reputation has only been awarded 3 times so far to the [three recipients of the badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5850/bluebook). I'm not yet sure why more people haven't received that type of reputation.

Comment: Hmm, so the answer (and Doc) just has to be voted on after the fact, not *answered* after the Documentation is edited

Comment: It's weird: I posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38631049/1983854) to an old question linking to an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/awk/1403/variables/4576/command-line-variable-assignment#t=201607281110450380112) that already had +1. Despite getting a +1 in my answer, I didn't get the Bluebook badge. Could it be that it needs to be an answer to a new question?