# Additional points for citing an example?

Tags: support, documentation, documentation-examples

When I got my Bluebook badge I got 5 extra points because I cited an example. However the following time I cited an example (not one I'd contributed to) I got a Creditor badge but no additional rep was awarded.

Is it the case that if you cite an example of your own, or something that you've contributed to, that you get more rep, but otherwise no, or has the entire 'extra rep' thing been scrapped?

Just wondering/seeking clarification. I don't think users deserve extra rep for stuff they didn't contribute to anyway, so I wasn't bothered about the rep [on second occasion], but would like to know if the rep is still available for own examples.

Maybe a moderator could reply - is this bonus rep awarded on a 'first-time' basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [help center describes](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) the reputation gain:

> - first time an answer that cites documentation you contributed to is upvoted: +5

These descriptions by their terseness leave out a few restrictions, however:

1. Only when an answer is upvoted *after* the link is added are you eligible for the +5.
2. Your own votes don't count. So you can't edit in a link to someone else's answer, upvote it, and reap the reward. (Though everyone else who contributed *will* be eligible.)
3. You can only earn +5 once for each answer even if it's upvoted many times or includes links to many of Docs you contributed to.

But the key thing is that you won't get reputation for the same citation that earns you the Creditor badge and you will get reputation for the same citation that earns you the Bluebook badge. (In fact, that's [how the badge is triggered](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328836/1438).)

Comment: I know this is now moot, but the later upvote requirement made it harder for someone to edit the post with the citation; even an accidental citation removal costs the example author -5, and a rollback won't reinstate the +5, until there is another upvote on the citating answer. Real-world example: [Sunset of Documentation BETA and removal of documentation link](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355792). Something to bear in mind for future reputation systems.