# Linking to Documentation gives you +5 reputation

Tags: discussion, documentation

I answered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38687547/check-for-constraints-before-insert/38687721#38687721) here and referred to one article I contributed to documentation in the initial days. I got 5 rep as you can see from below screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Why do we need to get rep for referring to documentation? Can we take this back?

**Update:**
I voted myself on my article just randomly,but that was on day of documentation came live and i got a rep today

Comment: You also get a badge if you contributed to the linked docs

Comment: Are you sure that the +5 rep was for linking to documentation instead of an upvote to your example there?

Comment: @Lamak:  I am 100% not sure,but as you can see that question has only one upvote and upvote in my article was mine when i wrote the article.I just upvoted to see how this works and i can upvote mine.To Clarify that upvote was done on same day when i wrote the article

Comment: [Your reputation tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2975396/thegameiswar?tab=reputation) lists this as *topic cited* (+5) and seemingly it has occured at the same time as the upvote on the answer. A similar thing occured to me, but there it was *  example cited* and this hasn't occured to me after this incident. (I haven't checked though, if one of my upvoted answers was one with a link to one of my examples.)

Comment: Related: [Additional points for citing an example?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330264/additional-points-for-citing-an-example)

Comment: @GertArnold At this point I think it would be better to close the other question as dupe of this one.

Comment: I would add [tag:bug] to this

Comment: @JGreenwell I think you mean [meta-tag:bug]

Comment: @DavidG whoops, wrong tag shortcut - yeah I mean adding bug as this cannot be a desired behavior (+5 for own linked post not just for people referencing)

Comment: @JGreenwell Having said that, I don't think it's a bug, I'm pretty sure that's how it was intended to work. If anything, it's a feature request, but I think discussion is the best place to start.

Comment: its an incentive to link to our subpar docs instead of official docs. more rep for crap. yay!

Comment: @Gordon, I agree, linking to official documentation is a good practice, and we shouldn't have people do things instead of that.

Comment: @SeinopSys You get a badge for linking to a Documentation topic you *didn't* contribute to, as well. 'Bluebook' for one you've contributed to, and 'Creditor' for one you haven't.

Comment: I agree with @Gordon, there shouldn't be any encouragement to choose unofficial doc over official.

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, almost all Docs reputation [comes from Example upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334005/1438). That's not terribly surprising since:

1. we haven't nerfed example upvote [quite yet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333420/1438),
2. early in the beta, many people decide to press the upvote button to see what it did,
3. reputation from citations is [somewhat restricted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334095/1438),
4. most of the great Examples and Topics are yet to be written (knock on wood), and
5. people haven't really gotten into the habit of citing Stack Overflow Documentation.

In the long run, however, I hope citation reputation actually catches up and even passes upvote reputation. One of the problems we are seeing is that it's hard to evaluate the usefulness of Documentation in the abstract. Remember how [Jeff threatened a kitten](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/) because people weren't voting on questions?

> Personally, I'm not convinced this problem is necessarily solvable, because it might represent the natural "market value" of questions and answers. Users intuit that **answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system** and tend to favor answers in their voting. After all, the world is awash in endless questions, but answers—great answers—are a precious and rare commodity indeed.

Until it helps a real developer understand or get started with a topic, Documentation hasn't earned its salt. One of the fundamental problems I have when programming is [finding the right bit of documentation](http://jericson.github.io/2016/08/25/long_tail_docs.html) quickly and without distraction. The other day, I forgot to how to zip a directory and looked it up in [the manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zip). In order to find a useful example, you gotta read past this line<sup>1</sup>:

```
zip [-aABcdDeEfFghjklLmoqrRSTuvVwXyz!@$] [--longoption ...] [-b path] [-n suffixes] [-t date] [-tt date] [zipfile [file ...]] [-xi list]
```

So when an answer that cites Documentation gets an upvote, it verifies that the Topic or Example was useful *and* encourages people to link to Documentation they contributed to. We think this will produce a virtuous circle where people improve answers by linking to relevant Documentation and improve Documentation in order use it in answers.

In the comments, I see some concern that we aren't encouraging linking to official documentation. People *should* link to official documentation whenever it makes an answer better. But (as with the zip command) sometimes you need something more exampley. Since you generally [can't edit official documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/330003/1438) directly, there's no way to break into the virtuious cycle I described. So while I wouldn't be opposed<sup>2</sup> to awarding reputation for citing all sorts of documentation, I don't think it would be nearly as useful as linking to Stack Overflow Documentation.

---

Footnotes:

1. It would be quicker to list the ASCII characters that are *not* options. Manpages do a relatively good job at documenting things, but they can be really dense at times.
2. In principle. In practice, I don't see how that would work given a seemingly endless supply of [technologies](https://stackoverflow.com/tags).