# Reputation points on Documentation

Tags: discussion, documentation, reputation

Do we really want the reputation points for good documentation to be less than the reputation points for good answers to questions? I think it should be 10 reputation points for upvotes for the original poster and the editors get reputation points as described.

To go more into this, I think that saying other people can significantly improve documentation is true, but not fair to the original poster. What if it is originally very good? Documentation should operate off of similar principles as those of the main site.

If you were able to flag examples as very low quality or for deletion, and then *write your own example* to replace it, that would be clearer than fixing a terrible example or even a mediocre one. The other point of view is like saying that one should edit a terrible answer to make it wonderful instead of posting your own. (Maybe an "obsolete" flag should be added so when a better example comes up, the old one can be deleted?) Edits have their place, but at some point it is better to post your own answer.

Of course, there does have to be a line somewhere, though I don't know how that should be drawn. I guess I would say that if an answer is low-quality, terrible, awful, then it is okay to write your own answer. If it is mediocre or better, then it is not okay, and maybe there would be a way to flag that as well.

Also in this vein, the number of characters is, I think, a subjective way to do it. I get edits will be reviewed, but there is always the possibility of junk somehow getting in if it looks good enough. Besides, good edits could add images, or delete unnecessary bits, or split up an example, and this is not recognized by the current system. I understand that rewarding deletion could, um, end up badly, but that is unfair to the people who do it for a good reason. Besides, isn't that what the review queues are for (though, of course, there are always exceptions).

I would also suggest that if a rollback occurs, the editor(s) whose edit was effectively deleted by the rollback should be removed from the reputation cycle. Of course, if the rollback is rolled back (geesh) that would cancel.

I do not have a good suggestion for replacements, but I'm bringing these up as things to consider. Thanks, and again, any feedback is appreciated. If something is not clear, I'd be glad to clarify. I will be adding any ideas I think of, but these are the main ones. I love the idea of documentation, and props to everyone who is working on it, whether a user or part of the team. Thanks for your hard work!

**Note**: I originally posted this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/333894/6723642), but a user suggested I post it in its own question so it gets more attention/feedback. I'd appreciate any feedback.

**Edit:**

This is in response to Nicol Bolas' answer.

> Editing examples and adding new examples are not considered different activities.

Yes. That is very true. But (looking back on this, I didn't make this clear, and I apologize) I am suggesting this not because of ownership for the original poster, but because I think anyone who makes a significant improvement to the documentation (such as creating it outright) should get more reputation points, and I believe the assigning of reputation points to edits is flawed for the reasons I explain up above.

These reasons include not allowing for deletion, short edits that significantly improve the post, and it just being generally arbitrary in my mind.

**My suggestion:**

This might be terrible, if so, just let me know. However, what if, once the review queue is set up, not only do items get reviewed/rejected, but "importance" is rated, say, on a scale of 1 to 5 (where 1 is somewhat helpful/minor and 5 is extremely helpful; non-helpful things are not on this list as these would be outright rejected). Reputation for the edit is calculated based on this rating, perhaps 10 rep/upvote for the top helpfulness rating and 1 rep/upvote for the lowest helpfulness rating (or maybe even 0 for that rating, I don't know). Since there would be multiple people approving, the rating would get the same cross-checking.

> Now why it is that we give reputation for something over which there is no ownership is a much better question.

Why is there a difference between helping the community via questions and answers and helping the community via documentation? Reputation points isn't about ownership; according to the help center "Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you". Surely if someone writes good documentation, or helps write good documentation, we should trust them more? Reputation points is also, to some extent, about helping the community (i.e., which answer was the most helpful). Documentation is helpful; that should be represented.

Finally, I don't know how this reputation points should be represented (in the overall Stack Overflow reputation points, separate reputation points, or some other way) though I'm leaning toward a separate reputation points count, or maybe something based off of tag (i.e., extra reputation points in a tag's documentation only shows when you answer questions in that particular tag).

Comment: Did you read the recent docs update?

Comment: @TravisJ, yes, and these are points I wanted to bring up because of that update.

Comment: I'd like to note though that documentation is projected to gather more upvotes in general per example. Documentation is small, as opposed to the millions of SO questions; upvotes there will be concentrated on maybe a few thousand examples later on.

Comment: @bwoebi, sure, but, for example, a question is more narrow, it'll help less people. I think the number of people documentation helps makes up for that. Besides, there's actually a ton of documentation - tons of tags, and tons of pages/examples, and more being added all the time.

Answer (score 14):

> I think it should be 10 rep for upvotes for the original poster and the editors get rep as described.

This idea requires attaching *ownership* to an example. That the OP of an example somehow has primacy over it.

On Q&A, it requires 1 rep to post an answer. But it requires **2000** before you can edit one freely. On Docs.SO, the requirements for posting a new example without review is no different than the requirements for editing one. Editing examples and adding new examples are not considered different activities.

So clearly, ownership of an example is not a concept that Docs.SO recognizes. You have no more ownership of an example than the next person.

Now why it is that we give *reputation* for something over which there is no ownership is a much better question.

Comment: See, though, I disagree with this. They are not considered different activities, true. But, I suppose, I am suggesting this not because of ownership for the original poster (I really should've clarified this, sorry, I'll add it) but because I think anyone who makes a significant improvement to the documentation (such as creating it outright) should get more rep (for now I'll leave alone the question of whether or not there should *be* rep) and I believe the assigning of rep to edits is flawed for the reasons I explain in my question. I'll be adding an update to explain further.

Comment: The problem with not knowing who owns which part of what -- since the entire Docs feature at present is "you touched it, you own it" -- is that it makes reorganizing content terribly difficult. When the structure was designed along the idea of wearing a path into the ground where one did not exist, not being able to properly organize examples is altering what that path should have looked like.

Comment: @TravisJ: "*it makes reorganizing content terribly difficult*" I would say that this is a problem with the poorly-defined nature of Docs.SO mainly. Examples *ought* to be something that is sufficiently small that "reorganizing content" would be impossible. You could move them around to different topics (which will retain the history and so forth), but they should never grow to the size where moving *parts* of an example is something that someone should want to do.

Comment: Dead on with that comment, @Nicol. This is something we're gonna probably just have to bit the bullet on; there's no good way to track revisions across the breakup of an omnibus "example".

Answer (score 9):

First, let's have a bit of clarification regarding how reputation *currently* interacts with Documentation...

There are currently three ways to earn reputation via Documentation:

1. Submitting an edit earns +2 on approval.
2. An upvote on an example to which you're a substantive contributor earns you +5.
3. The first upvote on an *answer* that references a topic or example you've contributed to earns you +5.

Right now, [most of the reputation being earned in Docs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329459/how-much-reputation-is-given-per-documentation-post-per-day-convert-to-communi/329740#329740) is coming from #1 and #2, with #2 being by far the leader. However, this is probably an anomaly - as with all new systems, there was a huge stampede of interest at the very start, resulting in the creation of a tremendous number of examples and an even larger number of votes. Because it was new, and this was something new folks could do. I don't expect most of those votes actually *meant* much; I'm especially skeptical of the idea that most of them indicate anything approaching *helpfulness in terms of solving a problem* - for example, I highly doubt there was *that much* pent-up confusion over how Java Arrays worked.

This idea of temporary exuberance is born out by the data:

[image: Documentation reputation sources over time]

Reputation being earned from voting dropped *substantially* from its peak before leveling out; a raw count of votes per week follows roughly the same trend. So for now, let's consider this a very weak signal that may, over a long period of time, become somewhat stronger. So far, this is actually pretty close to how Q&A works...

But remember, you *also* earn reputation when documentation you've contributed to is linked to from answers... In other words, you earn reputation when it is *used*. It's a lot easier to call *someone using your work* a reasonable metric for it being useful.

Thus far, this source of reputation has been kind of a *slow burn* - in the graph above, it fluctuates between 1 and 3 thousand points per week, dwarfed by the tens of thousands of reputation from votes. I would tend to expect this to continue for... A good while. Because writing useful documentation is hard, and *finding* useful documentation is even harder.

So what you have now is a system that *in theory* lets useful writing double-dip: earn rep up-front for votes that are mostly based around the notion that an example *might* be useful, earn rep later on as folks writing answers *actually find it useful*, then maybe earn rep again as the folks *reading* those answers follow the links and vote on your examples. Plus it applies these rules to everyone who contributes more than a trivial amount of content.

In practice, we're far short of this scenario right now: most of what's been written hasn't been proven useful thus far. And that's ok; I'd prefer if it was a *little bit* harder to earn reputation in Docs until we've had some time to hash out some of the disagreements, as long as in the long-term your productive effort is rewarded.

Comment: That makes sense; thank you for responding. The one thing I didn't really see addressed in your answer, though, is about the (for example) character count deciding how helpful an edit is. (I did add an edit including a suggestion for that.) I'd appreciate it if you could tell me what is wrong with that.