# Creditor badge not received

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation, badges

I posted an answer to a question on Stack Overflow two days ago: [Are local variables not accessible within generator functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430360/are-local-variables-not-accessible-within-generator-functions/39430405#39430405).

I included a link to [this Documentation entry](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/263/variable-scope-and-binding/20367/local-vs-global-scope#t=201609102050263941088) (*Note the formatting, obviously this link is recognized as a Stack Overflow Documentation link*), hoping that I would earn the [Creditor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/5851/creditor). Linking the documentation should be enough according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328503/5952681) Meta answer.

Until now I did **not** receive the badge...

What went wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was upvoted shortly after you wrote the initial draft. Since you [edited in the citation](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39430405/revisions), there hasn't been an upvote on that answer. [As with the Bluebook badge](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/328836/1438), the Creditor badge is triggered by an upvote on an answer that cites Documentation. So you'll have to wait for someone to upvote to get the badge.

Comment: Now I'm completely confused :) I saw the part about gaining rep when the answer is upvoted, but I thought that this is completely unrelated to awarding the badge! The description of the badge is very clear to me: **First citation of a topic or example you haven't contributed to, in an answer you posted.** Nothing related to upvotes at all!

Comment: @linusg: Almost all badges have hidden triggers that generally don't matter much. (See the somewhat curious [Curious badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234956/1438).) We can probably update the description, but it must remain terse. I'm not sure we can easily explain that the vote has to come after the edit. (There's also very little you can do about it, since you can't vote on your own answer. ;-) Barring some inspiration, I think we'll just leave the description as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Still a bit misleading, but the docs are still beta :)

Comment: @JonEricson Generally don't matter much *except they matter a great deal in that they determine whether you actually **get** the badge* ;-)